# ROS2 simple commander issue

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, nav2

Hello i use ROS2 humble on ubuntu jammy 22.04
I have been trying to build this for three days
this is repository i tried to use:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_simple_commander

terminal returns this:
[image]

it seems like the function expects two arguments instead of four but if i change the code deleting two of them it gets worse because it lacks certain handlers

Code from noise generator test cpp file

```
  '''  
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "nav2_mppi_controller/tools/noise_generator.hpp"
#include "nav2_mppi_controller/models/optimizer_settings.hpp"
#include "nav2_mppi_controller/models/state.hpp"
#include "nav2_mppi_controller/models/control_sequence.hpp"
#include <rclcpp_lifecycle/lifecycle_node.hpp>
#include "../include/nav2_mppi_controller/tools/parameters_handler.hpp"


// Tests noise generator object

class RosLockGuard
{
public:
  RosLockGuard() {rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);}
  ~RosLockGuard() {rclcpp::shutdown();}
};
RosLockGuard g_rclcpp;

using namespace mppi;  // NOLINT

TEST(NoiseGeneratorTest, NoiseGeneratorLifecycle)
{
  // Tests shuts down internal thread cleanly
  NoiseGenerator generator;
  mppi::models::OptimizerSettings settings;
  settings.batch_size = 100;
  settings.time_steps = 25;

  auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode>("node");
  node->declare_parameter("test_name.regenerate_noises", rclcpp::ParameterValue(false));
  ParametersHandler handler(node);

  generator.initialize(settings, false, "test_name", &handler);
  generator.reset(settings, false);
  generator.shutdown();
}

TEST(NoiseGeneratorTest, NoiseGeneratorMain)
{
  // Tests shuts down internal thread cleanly
  auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode>("node");
  node->declare_parameter("test_name.regenerate_noises", rclcpp::ParameterValue(true));
  ParametersHandler handler(node);
  NoiseGenerator generator;
  mppi::models::OptimizerSettings settings;
  settings.batch_size = 100;
  settings.time_steps = 25;
  settings.sampling_std.vx = 0.1;
  settings.sampling_std.vy = 0.1;
  settings.sampling_std.wz = 0.1;

  // Populate a potential control sequence
  mppi::models::ControlSequence control_sequence;
  control_sequence.reset(25);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i != control_sequence.vx.shape(0); i++) {
    control_sequence.vx(i) = i;
    control_sequence.vy(i) = i;
    control_sequence.wz(i) = i;
  }

  mppi::models::State state;
  state.reset(settings.batch_size, settings.time_steps);

  // Request an update with no noise yet generated, should result in identical outputs
  generator.initialize(settings, false, "test_name", &handler);
  generator.reset(settings, false);  // sets initial sizing and zeros out noises
  generator.setNoisedControls(state, control_sequence);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cvx(0), 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cvy(0), 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cwz(0), 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cvx(9), 9);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cvy(9), 9);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cwz(9), 9);

    enter code here

  // Request an update with noise requested
  generator.generateNextNoises();
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  generator.setNoisedControls(state, control_sequence);
  EXPECT_NE(state.cvx(0), 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cvy(0), 0);  // Not populated in non-holonomic
  EXPECT_NE(state.cwz(0), 0);
  EXPECT_NE(state.cvx(9), 9);
  EXPECT_EQ(state.cvy(9), 9);  // Not populated in non-holonomic
  EXPECT_NE(state.cwz(9), 9);

  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvx(0), 0, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvy(0), 0, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cwz(0), 0, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvx(9), 9, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvy(9), 9, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cwz(9), 9, 0.3);

  // Test holonomic setting
  generator.reset(settings, true);  // Now holonomically
  generator.generateNextNoises();
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  generator.setNoisedControls(state, control_sequence);
  EXPECT_NE(state.cvx(0), 0);
  EXPECT_NE(state.cvy(0), 0);  // Now populated in non-holonomic
  EXPECT_NE(state.cwz(0), 0);
  EXPECT_NE(state.cvx(9), 9);
  EXPECT_NE(state.cvy(9), 9);  // Now populated in non-holonomic
  EXPECT_NE(state.cwz(9), 9);

  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvx(0), 0, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvy(0), 0, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cwz(0), 0, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvx(9), 9, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cvy(9), 9, 0.3);
  EXPECT_NEAR(state.cwz(9), 9, 0.3);

  generator.shutdown();
}
'''
```

I know it might be trivial issue but i am new to ubuntu and trying to make use of ros for me engineering project, thanks for help in advance

Comment: Welcome to RSE. For readabiltiy, please format your snippets/terminal outputs properly, e.g. as code or quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted this on github and the issue was found. Cross linking answer: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/4002